# Trying to find palindrome number

Tags: java, palindrome

I am trying to find palindrome no but every time it is showing false for every no even for 121
please Help....

```
public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        if(x<0 || x%10==0){
            return false;
        }
        int rev = 0;
        while(x!=0){
            rev=(rev*10)+(x%10);
            x/=10;
        }
        
        if(x==rev){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tIlR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because after your while loop ends, `x will be 0`, you have to act on a copy instead

```
   public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
        int num = x;
        if(x<0 || x%10==0){
            return false;
        }
        int rev = 0;
        while(x!=0){
            rev=(rev*10)+(x%10);
            x/=10;
        }
        
        if(num==rev){
            return true;
        }
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As an option, you may create something like this:

```
public boolean isPalindrome(int x) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(x);
    return sb.toString().equals(sb.reverse().toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You function can be as simple as below

```
public static void main(String args[]){  
  int r,sum=0;    
  int n=454;//It is the number variable to be checked for palindrome  
  
  if(isPalindrome(n)) {
   System.out.println("palindrome number ");   
  } else {
   System.out.println("not palindrome number ");   
  }
     
}  

public boolean isPalindrome(int n)  {
  while(n>0){    
   r=n%10;  //getting remainder  
   sum=(sum*10)+r;    
   n=n/10;    
  }    

   return n==sum;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is useful:

```
       public static boolean palindrome(int n) {
                int nPalindrome = 0;
                int nCopy = n;
                while (n != 0) {
                   nPalindrome = nPalindrome *10 + n % 10;
                   n = n / 10;
            }
            if (nCopy == nPalindrom) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
    
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is build the new number as you reduce the original.  Then compare the two.

```
for (int i : new int[]{121,12321, 123,34543,20012}) {
    System.out.printf("%6d - %s%n", i, isPalindrome(i));
}
    
public static boolean isPalindrome(int numb) {
    int n = 0;
    for (int b = numb; b > 0;) {
        n *= 10;
        n += b%10;
        b/=10;
    }
    return n == numb;
}
```

Prints

```
   121 - true
 12321 - true
   123 - false
 34543 - true
 20012 - false
```